# Is it possible to manually switch string resources at runtime?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

Let me start by describing my problem. I am working on a large Android application that has a large number of layouts and strings (all in strings.xml). A new requirement has been made that requires some of the strings to be different depending on a condition at startup (think all instances of "cat" being replaced with "dog"). This condition does NOT depend on anything with the device (locale, size, resolution, etc.): it only depends on something within the business logic.

The simplest approach would be to create new copies of all the layout files that use the strings that have "cat", and in those new layout copies instead use strings that have "dog". However, this is not entirely feasible due to the number of layouts, as well as future maintenance concerns of basically duplicated layouts.

I know this isn't a discussion forum, so I have an approach I'd like to focus on. It seems to me the problem is closely related to normal resource configuration/locale, where different resources are provided due to attributes of the device. Is there a way to get this working for my situation? The differences are the desired configuration is only known at runtime and there isn't an existing resource qualifier that makes sense (we might translate into French, for example, so I don't want to piggyback on that). I can't imagine my problem is unique, though.

If there's another approach I should use let me know, although I don't want to go too far in the discussion route because SO frowns upon it. Frankly it's probably risky even asking this here, but I don't know where else to ask it.

Comment: Maybe use string.format() and have formatted strings in your resource xml? Example would be `string.format("hey, This is a %s", "dog");` wherever you want replacement. Your string xml would contain <string name="my_string">This is a %s</string>. This solution would work in code though and won't be easily (or at all) feasible entirely in the xml I believe. Your layout could still have `android:text="@string/my_string"` but your business logic needs to format it accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that but like you said it wouldn't work for XML. The problem is the vast majority of the replacements I need to do are in labels that aren't presently touched by any code, so that would be a fair amount of changes.

Answer (score 0):

I can think on several solutions:

You can set the string on runtime like `yourTextView.setText(R.string.any_string)` with:

1) A To have some resources strings for you business logic.
2) A [placeholder string](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling),

```
getResources().getString(R.string.tempale, "your value")
```

3) Get the string from web service if that posible